# Alphabetic string theory

Tags: wordplay, visual, combinatorics, letters, letter-sequence

**According to alphabetic string theory, the words we see are merely the visible portions of highly convoluted loops of multi-dimensional alphabetic string.**

**For example, here is what we see in our space-time:**

[image: example_word]

**But if we were able to perceive the entire loop of multi-dimensional alphabetic string, it would look something like this:**

[image: example_solution]

**In case you're having trouble seeing the alphabetic loop, here it is annotated:**

[image: example_solution_annotated]

**Are you ready for your PhD in alphabetic string theory?  See if you can show the entire alphabetic loop for this word:**

[image: challenge_word]

Comment: Do we need to stay within the black rectangle? Or even stay within a one-tile border like the example?

Comment: @xnor — You may assume that the black region is unbounded and extends infinitely.

Comment: What conditions for the central word are needed to make this possible?

Comment: This is really underdetermined.

Comment: @Simd — At the very least, the word cannot use any letter more than once, and the letters must be appropriately spaced within the word.  For example, the word REALIST won't work because the R and the S are too far apart.  Beyond those two conditions, I'm not sure yet.  I am currently running my solver on all the words which meet the two conditions to see if any of them don't generate a solution.  Then we can explore why.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica — Yeah, it is.  Lots of valid solving paths.  I believe HAZELNUTS has 2804 solutions.  But it's fun, though!

Comment: There are more conditions to make this solvable, for example the 'word' AFKDIN doesn't allow an alphabetic string because while you could connect the A-D, F-I and K-N individually, you can't put all three paths without intersections. Unfortunately AFKDIN is not in any dictionary but there may be proper dictionary words that have this problem as well.

Comment: @quarague — Excellent point and well summarized.  In order to connect any two letters, you have to create a sort of semicircle, either across the topside or across the bottomside.  If there are enough of them, there could be too many semicircles blocking the way to make the next connection.  In other words, you've created one of those topological figures that can't be embedded in the plane without intersection:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem

Comment: If we can prove that no word in the dictionary has the same problem as "AFKDIN" then that should be worthy of a Ph. D. in Alphabetic String Theory :-) In fact, the letter N is unnecessary here.

Comment: @happystar — I'm starting to see some words with problems:  BAKESHOP, LAYOVERS, OUTREACH.  Alphabetic String Theory might be on shaky ground here.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I present: Hazelnut string theory!

> [image]

Comment: Very nice, though there does seem to be a bit of uncertainty there.

Comment: @DanielMathias in what way?

Comment: OPQR could also be below, WX has multiple connection possibilities.

Comment: @DanielMathias ahh gotcha, yep there's a couple different ways to solve, I think the rough idea remains the same though, a lot of the above is forced

Comment: The given solution lacks an abstract and list of references to other related puzzles on PSE. Other than that, good job!